Issue with using custom Image from Google Artifact Registry to run Github workflow using Workload Identity Federation
I use Workload Identity Federation for keyless Authentication in my Workflow.
I have been trying to use my custom image in my github workflow in the following way;
jobs:
  setup_and_authenticate:
    name: 'Demo stage'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/my-demo-project/workflow-repository/ubuntu-custom-image:latest

During the execution, i have been getting the following error;
Error response from daemon: Head "https://europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/v2/my-demo-project/workflow-repository/ubuntu-checkov-image/manifests/latest": denied: Unauthenticated request. Unauthenticated requests do not have permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" on resource "projects/my-demo-project/locations/europe-west3/repositories/workflow-repository" (or it may not exist)
The service account that i use have the required permissions.
Now, i understand that there is some sort of authentication required. But, i dont have a clear idea on using WIF at this section to make it work. Can someone help?
